# Gnuplot: symbol 'X' in red in the place of an absent value

Tags: variables, colors, gnuplot

Please, i have a question about gnuplot.

Here is the file i work on:

```
1   129 130
2   129 129
3   129 130
4   129 129
5   129 ---
```

As you see the last line has no value in the third column.
Here is my command:

```
plot "mesuresSecondscen.txt" using 1:2 with linespoints lt 26 pt 26 tit 'Kernel of 129s' axis x1y1, "mesuresSecondscen.txt" using 1:3 with linespoints lt 21 pt 13 tit 'With-My-Approach' axis x1y1
```

Example:      http://tinyurl.com/p2rfde9
I'd like to set the symbol 'X' in red in the place of the absent value

Is that possible please ?
Thank you so much for answer.

Kind regards.

Comment: I cannot see your image (maybe wrong permissions?). Can you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental problem with your question, which is that you want to place a red "X", but *where*? If the value is missing you need to provide the coordinate value in some other way to know where you want to place the symbol. Anyway, for demonstration purposes I will assume you want to place it where the second column value lies. The function `valid(n)` can test if the value in column `n` is valid (returns `1`) or not (returns `0`). Using a conditional expression we can ask gnuplot to place a big red "X" at `y = column(2)` every time it encounters non-valid data:

```
plot "mesuresSecondscen.txt" using 1:2 with linespoints lt 26 pt 26 tit 'Kernel of 129s' axis x1y1, \
"mesuresSecondscen.txt" using 1:3 with linespoints lt 21 pt 13 tit 'With-My-Approach' axis x1y1, \
"mesuresSecondscen.txt" u 1:(valid(3) == 1 ? 1/0 : $2) pt 2 lc 1 ps 3 lw 3
```

The last line tests if the third column's value is valid, if it is valid (`valid(3) = 1`) it ignores that point, if it is not valid (`valid(3) = 0`) it places a big red "X" at `y = column(2)`.

[image]